# Empty fields can get inserted into my database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code. I try to use my Submit button to insert the code into the database, but every time I use it and refresh the browser, empty fields get inserted into the database.

```
<?php 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

//create connection
$cn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "milege");

//check connection
if ($cn->connect_error) {
    echo "Connection failed!". $cn->connect_error;
}

// once the button is clicked
if (isset($_POST['submitForm'])) {
    //the values in the boxes
    $name = $_POST['fname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confpass = $_POST['confpass'];
    $interest = $_POST['interest'];
    $info = $_POST['info'];

    //echo "connection successfully";
    //Insert into table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO miltb(name, email, password, interest, info, productorder) VALUES('$name', '$email', '$password', '$interest', '$info', 'none' )";
}

if ($cn->query($sql) == true) {
    ?><script>alert ("INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY!");</script><?php
} else {
    echo "error: " . $sql . "\n" . $cn->error;
}

$cn->close();
?>
```

How would I fix it?

Comment: can we see your form too? Check the forms method is `method='post'` and attempt to `var_dump($_POST);` to ensure content is coming through

Comment: I hope you're not intending on going live with this.

Comment: Try and run the command directly in something like phpmyadmin. This will help to check the query.

Comment: Apart from all the security problems, why are you closing your `if` block after defining the sql? That makes no sense.

Comment: also post your form

Comment: as jeroen points out.. move the `}` after your $sql = line to be just before your closing PHP tag. Also, we need to see the code for the form that submits to this code.

Comment: please put last `ìf else `  block inside  `ìf(isset($_POST['submitForm'])); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason empty fields get inserted in the database it's because you are not checking for empty fields, you need to check those empty fields first then if empty fields exists do not insert.**

Well man there's a lot that you need to learn, you need to learn about

[1.SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

2.[mysqli prepared](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [pdo prepared](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) statements.

3.[Password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

4. [Filter ,sanitize and validate user inputs](http://hhttp://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

**Never trust an input from the user, you must always treat a user input as if it comes from a dangerous hacker.**

Then you code with prepared statements should look like this :

```
<?php


//create connection
$cn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "milege");

//check connection
if ($cn->connect_error) {
        echo "Connection failed!" . $cn->connect_error;
}

$error = "";
// once the button is clicked
if (isset($_POST['submitForm'])) {


        // check for empty fiels

        if (empty($_POST['fname'])) {

                echo "Enter your name";
                $error++;
        } else {

                $name = userInput($_POST['fname']);

        }

        if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

                echo "enter email";
                $error++;
        } else {

                $email = userInput($_POST['email']);

                // validate email

                if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) {

                        echo "enter a valid email";
                        $error++;
                }
        }

        if (empty($_POST['password'])) {

                echo "enter password";
                $error++;
        } else {


                $password = userInput($_POST['password']);

                $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORS_DEFAULT); //hash the password
        }

        if (!empty($_POST['confpass']) && $_POST['confpass'] !== $_POST['password']) { //password confirmation

                echo "passwords does not match";
                $error++;
        }

        if (empty($_POST['interest'])) {

                echo "enter interests";
                $error++;
        } else {

                $interest = userInput($_POST['interest']);
        }

        if (empty($_POST['info'])) {

                echo "enter info";

                $error++;
        } else {

                $info = userInput($_POST['info']);
        }


        if ($error > 0) { // if we have errors don't insert to db

                echo "you have " . $error . " error(s) on your form plz fix them";


        } else { // no errors lets insert


                // prepare and bind
                $sql = $cn->prepare("INSERT INTO miltb(name, email, password, interest, info) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?)");
                $sql->bind_param("sssss", $name, $email, $hash, $interest, $info);

                if ($sql->execute()) {

                        echo "INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY!";
                } else {


                        echo "could not insert ";
                }





        }


        $sql->close();
        $cn->close();



}




function userInput($data)
{


        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;

}


?>
```

**Hope this will help and you will learn a thing or two, I stand to be corrected where I'm wrong**

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this to be sure values are inserted:

```
$name = isset($_POST['fname']) ? strval($_POST['fname']) : null;
if (empty($name)){
    echo "Name can't be empty!";
    exit();
}
```

Note: beware of [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Using php function `strval()` is the least possible secutiry, but atleast use that, if nothing more.